# Bootstrap dropdown menu is blank (white) in safari

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I'm running a site using bootstrap 2.3.2 and drupal 7. When the menu collapses below 980px, it drops down perfectly in every browser but safari. In safari the menu drops down, but below about 480px the links on it are either white or blank. If you hover over them, they show up.

Dev address:
http://schoensten.janeschindler.ch/cms/de

Screenshot problem: 
http://janeschindler.ch/ftp/broken.png

There is nothing in the style sheet tied to 480px in particular. If you add certain attributes to the links using safari's equivalent to firebug, the information panel (for example width:100%), they show up again. But if you set those properties in the css, or using javascript, it doesn't have any effect and they stay blank until you roll over them. If you use jquery to keep the menu open when the page loads ($('.nav-collapse').css("height", "auto");), the links show up when you load the page but not if you collapse the menu and open it again. The problem also shows in more recent versions of safari on an iphone.

Would be awfully grateful if someone had an idea how to fix this.

Comment: Just add a style to your own CSS.

Comment: Thanks – I tried that. But adding styles doesn't fix the problem, even if I specify the color, width and z-index of the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for the problem is to delay adding something to the css. Here's my jquery for the menu now.

```
$('.btn-navbar').toggle(function(){
    $('.nav-collapse').css("height", "auto");
    $('.nav-collapse')
        .delay(10)
                   .queue(function() {
                       $(this).css("color","black");
                       $(this).dequeue();
                   });
}, function () {
    $('.nav-collapse').css("height", 0);
    $('.nav-collapse')
        .delay(10)
                   .queue(function() {
                       $(this).css("color","white");
                       $(this).dequeue();
                   });

});
```